# Split input file to multiple files

Tags: java

I need to write a java code for splitting a large file to multiple smaller files.

My file looks like

```
Begin for all values of X
1 abc 5:40
2 pqr 6:40
3 xyz 7:40
End

Begin for all values of Y
1 ccc 9:40
2 ddd 8:40
3 lll 6:40
End
```

Output will be:

```
X.txt(Filename)
1 abc 5:40
2 pqr 6:40
3 xyz 7:40

Y.txt(Filename)
1 ccc 9:40
2 ddd 8:40
3 lll 6:40
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? SO is not a coding service. Please edit your question!

Comment: This is relatively easy to do. What code have you tried so far? Oh and...Is this for school?! :)

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear, you can split a string into string array through some expression with this...

```
String[] yourStringArray = yourString.split("regularExpression");
//here regular expression is the character by which you will split string
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code does what you need. To check file boundary I'm testing if the string starts with `Begin for all values of`, if you have any other condition it can be replaced with that one.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
            String line = null;
            BufferedWriter writer = null;
            while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.startsWith("Begin for all values of")) {
                    String fileName = line.substring(line.length() -1);
                    closeWriter(writer);

                    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName + ".txt"));
                }
                writer.write(line + "\n");
            }
            closeWriter(writer);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void closeWriter(Writer output) {
        try {
            if(output != null) {
                output.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```